# Facebook sharer iPhone integration

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-sharer

I use Facebook sharer.php in my iPhone app. everything works fine, but I have a small problem with authentication.

`I use this method: http://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=[some url].`

Problem is when I log me to Facebook I am redirected to my Facebook wall and not to Facebook sharer page. 
How to fix it ? I want to be after login redirected to sharer page. 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I fix this by using another facebook webview for login. Then open share webview, it won't open login page.

This is login [link](https://www.facebook.com/login.php) that I use